# Maps in Taipy GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, maps, taipy

Looking at the Taipy 1.0 GUI documentation (https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/), I couldn't find any graphics for maps.

Is this something that will be provided in the future?

Comment: Hey Alex, Feel free to join our Discord Server discord.com/invite/SNNsCDj9? and connect with like-minded individuals and collaborate on your web application buildings :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the coming weeks, for the June Release (Taipy 1.1), we will provide an initial version of map objects.
Furthermore, more complex map management functions will be part of future releases in 2022.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).